# How do I get full feature list of Wear OS?

Tags: rom, android-wear

I'm developing a custom version of Android system for a 'Android smart glass' device. I'm trying  to customize a new version of Android ROM that suits this type of wearable device.

Needs features such as bluetooth/wifi direct connection, power saving mode, etc.

After researching the Android community, I find Wear OS suits most of my needs. However, I can't get a full feature set of Wear OS.

How do I get a in-depth analysis or something like full featureset of Wear OS?